# Print statement and logging spring boot cucumber print twice on console, how i avoid this? can i print only once?

Tags: java, spring-boot, automation, cucumber, appium

Hi im newbie in springboot, i try to use this framework to my automation mobile project, the problem its on console the print statement and log print twice, why? how to solve this?

This my app class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

This my spring boot base test class

```
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class SpringBootBaseTest {

}
```

This my logback.xml

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

This my loginpagesteps class

```
public class LoginPageSteps {
  @Autowired
  LoginPage loginPage;

  @When("User click sign in button")
  public void userClickSignInButtonInLoginPage() {
    loginPage.testing();
  }
```

This my Login page class

```
@Slf4j
@Component("com.mobile.automation.LoginPage")
public class LoginPage {
  public void testing() {
    System.out.println("hello");
    log.info("hai");
  }
}
```

This my cucumber feature class

```
Feature: Login
  Scenario: Verify user can login with valid account
    Given User click sign in button
```

When i run my code

```
hello
07:19:50.900 [main] INFO  c.c.m.automation.pages.LoginPage - hai
hello
07:19:50.902 [main] INFO  c.c.m.automation.pages.LoginPage - hai
```